# How do I use ImageMagick to split photos in two AND output the files with a weird numbering scheme?

Tags: windows, imagemagick, numbering

I am not a programmer/coder at all, just someone that can google (poorly), so I have no real idea what I'm doing.

I have a bunch of pictures that I need to split in half and keep both halves. Someone told me that IM could automate that, and gave me:

```
magick convert .\input.jpg -crop 50%x100% output%02d.jpg
```

After messing around with it for a bit—I'm not really a Command Line type of person—I did more focused googling and came up with this to batch an entire directory:

```
mogrify -crop 50%x100% +repage -path PATHNAME NEWFILE%02d.jpg
```

My problem is that the pages output with the left side of image 0 as 0, the right side of image 0 as 1, the left side of image 1 as 2, etc. But I need them numbered differently with the pattern of 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6… because these photos are meant to be paginated right-to-left.

I gave myself a headache last night trying to figure out how to set this up and found 12-year-old posts saying `mogrify` can't do custom outputs and that I need to use a script. But I don't know anything at all about Windows scripting and string outputs and whatever else may be involved.

I'm at the point where I don't know what I don't know, so I can't just use Google as my outboard brain anymore.

Pls help, pls.

EDIT:
As suggested by joojaa, this is what the +swap argument is for. I can't figure out how to mark this as answered because I didn't create an account.

Comment: As a workaround how about doing like this? First rotate the full images 180 degrees. Then do the splitting and the numbering should be as you want. Then rotate the resulting half images 180 degrees.

Comment: Are you sure one can not use the swap directive?